# Display customer attribute in promotions page

Tags: magento-enterprise, shopping-cart-price-rules

Is it possible to bring the Customer attribute in the Shopping cart price rule section to make a conditions like catalog attributes are showing in the promotions page( use for Promo rule conditions).

Comment: In Magento enterprise is not provided same as product attribute, but it is provided Customer Segment functionality in customer attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Magento Enterprise you can do this but it requires 2 steps.

**1. Customer segmentation**

In the backend go to `Customers > Customer Segments` and create a new segment.

Choose a name, the websites it should be active on and make sure it's active. Now `save and continue edit` it and add conditions.

Here you can pick the attribute you want to filter on
[image]

**2. Shopping Cart rule**

Now go to `Promotions > Shopping Cart Price Rule` in the top menu and create a new rule.

On the conditions tab you can choose `Customer Segment` as condition and pick the segment just created